# Can we assign data like this example patientId: this.clientId or is this the wrong syntax to assign

Tags: angular

My question is when i assign this.clientId to patientId and i debug to check if this.clientid has data or not the data is received but when i submit the patientId carries null data below ill share the code for better understanding

```
patientReportForm=this.getGroup({patientId : this.clientId ,hubxCategoryId:"",notes:""})
getGroup(data:any=null)
{
  debugger
  data=data || {patientId : 0,hubxCategoryId :"",notes:""}
  console.log(data)
  return new FormGroup({
    patientId:new FormControl(data.patientId),
    hubxCategoryId :new FormControl(data.hubxCategoryId),
    notes:new FormControl(data.notes)
  })
}
```

[image: this.clientId data]

and this is the result after submit here patientId carries null data. or am i assigning this.clientId to patientid in wrong syntax.
[image: result]

Comment: Please provide a complete stackblitz link

Comment: im sharing the code but code will not run because required apis cant be added here. But this is a running code at my side

Comment: use `this.patientReportForm=this.getGroup(...) `-see that you declare the form and use "this". If you get the "this.clientId" from a service (or form a subscription to params), write the instruction **inside** the subscribe function

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look, I think your problem is synchronization.
The `clientId` is initialized in a `subscribe` in `ngOnInit()`, whereas you are using it in a variable definition:

```
patientReportForm = this.getGroup({patientId: this.clientId, hubxCategoryId: "", notes: ""});
```

To verify this is the issue, try to initialize the `clientId` to `100`, instead of `undefined`. Are you still seeing a `null`?

-- EDIT --

Based on the comments, you are probably using `this.clientId` before it is initialized.

Comment: if i give patientid : 100 yes i get the data but this.clientid works in other line of code but it doesnt work there. What might be the issue

Comment: @ManipuriVlogs No, I said initialize the `clientId` to `100`, where you declare it. Not the `patiendId`...

Comment: clientId will come dynamically from api. I cant declare static. Check the above image clientId 40 is coming dynamically from API

Comment: @ManipuriVlogs But you are using `this.clientId`. So, `clientId` is an instance variable of your class. Set its initial value to `100` not `undefined`.

Comment: now it carries 100 not 40.it should carry 40.

Comment: @ManipuriVlogs My point is that you are probably using `this.clientId` before it is initialized. If you set it to 100 and it appeared as 100 instead of `undefined`, then it verifies what I wrote in my answer. In which case, please re-read my answer.

Comment: yes you are right. How can i set the value of this.clientId to PatientId. As i shown in the above image this.clientid carries a value 40 which is coming dynamically from API. How can i set this.clientId to patientId in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Of course no wonder, now that I saw your stackblitz you are already manually setting it to `null` by adding this ternary expression in the `ngOnInit(){}` lifecyclehook at line 100.

```
this.clientId = params.id == undefined ? null : this.commonService.encryptValue(params.id, false);
```

`null` is neither a default type nor a default value. The default type is `any` and the default value is `undefined`.

Since your code does not run due to missing dependencies correcting that line will resolve your problem.

Also, you need use strict equality check `===` not the loose equality `==`. It can cause subtle bugs.

Comment: it doesnt work. This.clientId works i other line of code but it doesnt work when i use it there